# Default thread queue size for undertow

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, threadpool, undertow

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.8RELEASE version and Undertow 1.4.2 version. How can I find the default thread queue size and default thread pool size?

Comment: You can get default queue/pool size from UndertowWebServerFactory bean configuration.

Comment: I am using some dependency that has that configuration. in this case is there a way to check the default values?

Answer (score 0):

You can get default queue and default pool size from `UndertowWebServerFactory` bean configuration.

Trying below snippet to get the details.

```
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    
    @Configuration
    public class UndertowConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer undertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer() {
            return new UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(UndertowServletWebServerFactory factory) {
                    System.out.println("Thread queue size: " + factory.getBuilder().getIoThreads());
                    System.out.println("Thread pool size: " + factory.getBuilder().getWorkerThreads());
                }
            };
        }
    }
```